# Showing an isometry preserves angles

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry, diffeomorphism

If we have two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3 ,$ say $S_1, S_2 $. And we have an isometry $f:S_1 \rightarrow S_2$. Then we have two curves $\alpha $ and $\beta $ on $S_1$ that intersect at $t=0$.

I am trying to show that the angle between the curves $\alpha $ and $\beta $ on $S_1$ is the same as the angle between $f(\alpha) $ and $f(\beta) $ on $S_2$.

The angle between them, $\theta $, on $S_1$ is given by $$\cos \theta =\frac{\alpha '\cdot \beta'}{||\alpha' ||||\beta '||}$$

The angle between the transformed curves $\phi $ is given by $$\cos \phi =\frac{f(\alpha ')\cdot f(\beta)'}{||f(\alpha)' ||||f(\beta) '||}$$

but I don't know how to show they're the same. I can't see where I can use the fact that $f$ is an isometry.

Comment: What definition of isometry are you using?

Comment: A diffeomorphism that preserves lengths of curves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Isometries preserve inner product in tangent spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475664/isometries-preserve-inner-product-in-tangent-spaces)